# Latency in MediaRouter detection

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am writing an Android application which detects DLNA and Chrome devices. Application design language does not support putting cast button on ActionBar. Instead I need to poll the DLNA and Chrome devices and display in a list.

The code written for detecting cast devices is as follows:

```
mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID))
            .build();


    mMediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback();
    mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
            MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN);
```

Using the above code, I have trouble detecting the chrome devices. I takes ~10 minutes for the devices that are in the network to get detected. Sometimes it takes even more time. But using CastButton in the Actionbar, the devices are detected immediately.

How to detect the chrome devices without any latency?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you call `mMediaRouter.getRoutes()` and then rely on the callback to stay up-to-date as routes come and go. It may be the case that `MediaRouter` has already discovered your devices and depending on a number of factors, your callback may not receive a notification for such routes. If you see that in those cases `mMediaRouter.getRoutes()` has what you want, then you would need to filter the routes obtained by that call manually (using the same selector and `RouteInfo.matchesSelector(selector)`.

Comment: Thanks 4 reply. I did use `mMediaRouter.getRoutes()`. But it always gives me default route `Phone`. Even in the ex., [https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android] MediaRouterDiscoveryActivity.java, I see the same behavior. I have NexusPlayer in n/w. Launching the app with the above code doesn't detect the device. If it detects it takes more than ~10 minutes. Only default route gets detected in the call back initially. With MenuItem or MediaRouteButton, I see the nexus player without delay. Disabe/enable WIFI, it gets detected immediately in callback. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you happen to have any other cast (non Nexus Player) cast device to see if the same behavior is observed there too, or it is just your Nexus Player that exhibits that problem?

Comment: I have nexus player, Nvidia shield, technicolor android box and all exhibit same behavior

Comment: Added Chromecast in n/w. Even this too behaved the same way. But lock/unlock the phone, the callback comes. Any suggestions?! Only with action bar cast button the detection is fast. I have Nexus 5X and it only behaves correctly. all other phones behaves the same way